# Webscraper will not work

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I have followed a tutorial pretty much to the letter, and I want my scraper to scrape all the links to the specific pages containing the info about each police station, but it returns the entire site almost.

```
from urllib import urlopen
import re

f = urlopen("http://www.emergencyassistanceuk.co.uk/list-of-uk-police-stations.html").read()

b = re.compile('<span class="listlink-police"><a href="(.*)">')
a = re.findall(b, f)

listiterator = []
listiterator[:] = range(0,16)

for i in listiterator:
    print a 
    print "\n"

f.close()
```

Comment: Please cite the tutorial you followed.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap_DlSrT-iE I did notice he mentions beautifulsoup, but i know that my script uses none of it's functions

Comment: emergencyassistanceuk.co.uk is going to have no clue why they have so much traffic right now ... ;)

Comment: lol@Nix.. so true. On a more practical note, it's a static unchanging list so retieval and regexing is a tad pointless. Just cut+paste the source code into a word-processor or dreamweaver and convert to CSV.

Answer (score 7):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

f = urlopen("http://www.emergencyassistanceuk.co.uk/list-of-uk-police-stations.html").read()

bs = BeautifulSoup(f)

for tag in bs.find_all('span', {'class': 'listlink-police'}):
    print tag.a['href']
```

Comment: "Thanks, did just what I needed." is best expressed ["by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 3):

You are using regex to parse HTML. You shouldn't, because you end up with just this type of problem. For a start, the `.*` wildcard will match as much text as it can. But once you fix that, you will pluck another fruit from the Tree of Frustration. Use a proper HTML parser instead.

Answer (score -1):

There are over 1.6k links with that class on it.

I think its working correctly... what makes you think it's not working?

---

And you should definitely use *Beautiful Soup*, it's stupid simple and extremely useable.

Comment: Yeah, but it prints the html, i am trying to get it to print everything between the " " on the a tag. I thought this script does just that.

Comment: You should reword your question `but it returns the entire site almost` to my regex is too greedy.