# How to scrape in python into excel

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping

I would like to know how I would have a python web scrape dump all of it's results into excel.
It's not that I don't know how to webscrape, it's just I do not know how to scrape into excel.

Comment: Check [this other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257771/python-writing-to-excel-2007-files-xlsx-files)

Comment: http://writemycode.net - give us something to comment on please

Comment: I've developed a product that uses JavaScript rather than Python but sounds like what you need. It creates Excel so you can have multiple sheets. The demo and example projects that should provide an good start with it. [Script Scraper](http://www.scriptscraper.com/index.php) thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

You say you know [how to web-scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078612/webscraper-will-not-work), presumably into memory.

Then you just need to dump the contents into Excel. Use an [Excel Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698229/excel-python-api) .

Comment: It has been a while since the question you quoted and I have learned since then. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to introduce a full excel library, you can write an HTML table or CSV and Excel will happily import those. The downside with this is that you're limited to one worksheet and no formulaes.